# "relatedEntities.forEach is not a function" Typescript Error

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I am building a server with TypeScript and TypeOrm running PostgreSQL, and when I try to save a data related to this Entity on the database, I receive this error: "relatedEntities.forEach is not a function"

this is what my Entity looks like:

```
@Entity()
export class ServiceOrder {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column()
identifier: String;

@Column()
description: String;

@Column()
creationDate: String;

@Column()
requestedAt: String

@Column({ type: 'decimal', nullable: true })
exectutionValue: number | null;

@Column({ type: 'decimal', nullable: true })
chargedValue: number | null;

@Column({ type: 'text', nullable: true })
comments: String | null;

@OneToMany(() => CostCenter, (costCenter) => costCenter.serviceOrder, { nullable: true 
})
@JoinColumn()
costCenter: CostCenter;

@OneToMany(() => ServiceStatus, (serviceStatus) => serviceStatus.status)
@JoinColumn()
status: ServiceStatus;

@ManyToMany(() => ServiceCategory, (serviceCategory) => serviceCategory.serviceOrder, { 
nullable: true })
@JoinTable({
  name: "ServiceOrder_category",
  joinColumn: {
    name: "serviceOrder_id",
    referencedColumnName: "id"
  },
  inverseJoinColumn: {
    name: "serviceCategory_id",
    referencedColumnName: "id"
  }
})
category?: ServiceCategory[];
};
```

I believe the issue is with the Many to Many relationship, but I can't tell where the issue is.

This is the entity that the many to many relationship is stablished with:

```
@Entity()
export class ServiceCategory {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column()
category: string;

@ManyToMany(() => ServiceOrder, (serviceOrder) => serviceOrder.category, { nullable: 
true })
serviceOrder: ServiceOrder[] | null;
};
```

Can anyone tell what could be giving me this issue?

Comment: the problem lays where `relatedEntities` is used. Provided code is not relevant.

Comment: relatedEntities is part of the typescript module not his code